# Is there a way to implement both server.listen at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, port

My game is currently either set for online which is the top port or I would need to comment it out and put the local `server.listen(8081)` is there a way to run both?

Saves me from swapping it around when making changes locally and pushing it through git.

```
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);

server.listen(8081);   //listens to the localhost:8081
```

Comment: Set a prod/dev variable in your .env file and check for it. If dev listen on port 8081 if prod listen on `process.env.port || 5000`.

Comment: How do you run your server ? With a command line interface ?

Comment: Heroku is what I use to run it online, and locally just with Express/Node

Comment: You're looking for `server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081);`

Comment: Do you want it to listen on two different ports? Or just have a default port if the environment variable isn't declared?

Comment: Yes, the `process.env.PORT` and `8081` as the comment on top shows @BrahmaDev solved the question, many thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for having two ports would be as @Brahma Devv posted

`server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081);`

Posting this to help others out too, many thanks for the feedback.